# How do I compare dataframes that are too big to fit in memory using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I have potentially large dataframes, on the order of 10 columns and 1e6 rows, with different dimensions. Assume rows are unique in both dataframes. As these dataframes can't be loaded into memory, how do I find all the rows in one dataframe that exist in the other? I'm currently only working with smaller dataframes, but I'll have to figure this out soon.

I strongly prefer to use pandas but I'm open to using a different package (xarray?) if there are significant benefits. If you recommend a different package, please provide some code that does the comparison.

Here's how I do the comparison with pandas dataframes that fit in memory:

```py
import pandas as pd

def row_intersection(df1, df2):
    noNA = df2.fillna(0)
    return df1.fillna(0).apply(lambda x: (noNA==x).all(axis=1).any(), axis=1)

a = DataFrame({'a':[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
               'b':[ 1, pd.NA, 13, 14],
               'c':['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']})
b = DataFrame({'a':[3, 2, 4],
               'b':[1, pd.NA, 14],
               'c':['y', 'x', 'z']})

# there are equivalent rows in both dataframes:
print('row comparison:',(b.fillna(0).loc[[1,2]].values == a.fillna(0).loc[[1,3]].values).all())


print(row_intersection(a, b))
```

output:

```
row comparison: True
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Also, if there's a quick way to get the intersection of all rows in both frames in one pass I'd love to know. Right now I do that in two passes like this:

```
a_in_b = row_intersection(a, b)
b_in_a = row_intersection(b, a)
```

Comment: can you just split the dataframe into smaller parts and iterate through them?

Comment: I could but I don't know how to do that except clunkily, say by reading some part of two files into two dataframes and iterating over both files. I'm assuming this is a standard problem with a better solution, or at least standardized ways to handle the files. For instance pandas has an HDF5 interface but I have no idea if that is designed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way would be with a merge and a map -> merge has an `indicator` parameter, to determine which rows match:

```
(a.merge(b, indicator = True, how = 'left')['_merge']
  .map(lambda x: True if x == 'both' else False)
 )

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: _merge, dtype: object
```

This should be faster than the iteration you have in your function; for data that does not fit into memory; I could think of mmap; however I have not used it myself so can't give you any info on that. datatable, and dask may help.

Another option is to take the data and dump into sqlite; run your merge in there.

Comment: excellent, thanks for the tip about merge. can you say more about using pandas with sqlite? how does that solve the problem?

Comment: A database is equipped to hold large data; with sqlite you can do the merge to get your intersection and pull the final result bck to pandas, th returned data should be significantly less and fit into memory. Sqlite is easy to install. Assumption here is that u knw some sql

Comment: okay, so this would require handling the data with external sql tools and then processing in pandas? I know pandas has sql interfaces; would those handle this without writing code somewhere else?

Comment: Pandas works as an in memory tool. Yes you would have to write sql. There is pyspark and Dask though; you could explore them as well.